# How to upload file to o365 group files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, office365

How can I upload file to "group files"?

I tried this example: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904536.aspx

But this upload to site folder, not to group files.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no different storage for Groups.**

The files portion of Office 365 is in a secret SharePoint site collection that gets created and counts against your quota, but you can see it anywhere to manage it but you cannot navigate to it.

Every user that is a member of that group instead gets to see what's inside of that site from his or her OneDrive by clicking on Groups or directly through the group itself.

Comment: From what I found yesterday the only way to do this is to use OneDrive API. Which require registering app on azure, authenticate via oauth, and then proceed with api calls...

Comment: If you want to upload something to group, why don't you do directly by logging onto portal.office.com or simply by uploading using Onedrive App and adding it to group. 
Forgive me if I am wrong in interpreting your problem.

Comment: I don't have problem doing that manually. What I want is to build an application which can do that automatically.

Comment: @ShP Unfortunately, there is no way apart from using OneDrive API right now :( . I have written to O365 product team. I will get update you as and when there is any update.